# increase volume by a factor (wav file)

Tags: c, audio

Increase volume by a factor (wav file).

I wanted to scale a wav file by a factor.
When factor is 1 and 1.0 it works, when factor is like 2.0 or 0.3 the audio goes silenct.

Here is my code:

```
const int HEADER_SIZE = 44; 
float factor = 2.0;
uint8_t head[HEADER_SIZE];
int16_t buffer;

fread(head, sizeof(HEADER_SIZE), 
1,input);


fwrite(head, sizeof(HEADER_SIZE), 1, 
output);


while (fread( &buffer , 
sizeof(int16_t), 1, input)  == 1)
{
     buffer = buffer* factor;

    ***//buffer = buffer * 1.0  works 
    buffer = buffer * 2.0 or 0.9; does 
    not 
    work***
    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 
    1, output);
}
```

Comment: You might be hitting overflow. Check with audacity if your wav's amplitude is OK to have a 2x amplification.

Comment: You could check (display on the screen) the values of `buffer` before and after the multiplication, at least for the first samples.

Comment: should probably clamp the buffer to something like `buffer = clamp(buffer * 2, MAX_VOLUME)` and see if that improves it. that will get rid of the silence but will produce inconsistent volume.